# Где взять pyconfig.h?

Tags: c++, python, boost

Работаю в операционной системе OpenSUSE 13.2

При сборке возникает ошибка при подключении заголовочного файла:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
```

Команда для сборки:

```
g++ -c -g -w -std=c++11 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/kernel.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/kernel.o kernel.cpp
```

Вот что получаю на выходе:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:8,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from kernel.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error: pyconfig.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
 # include <pyconfig.h>
                       ^
```

Подскажите, как это исправить? Где взять pyconfig.h?

Comment: python-dev установлен?

Comment: Как написали выше, вам нужен пакет `python-dev`, который включает в себя необходимые заголовочные файлы.

Comment: python-dev в стоковом репозитории нет, только python-devel - если это он, то да, установлен

Comment: Поищите указанный файл через mc, может его все же нет на диске?

Comment: Искал - не было, хотел найти и скопировать. В итоге написал сюда

Comment: Возможно криво встал python-devel, попробуйте переставить.

Comment: Не помогло, py-devel для второй и третьей версии установлены.

Comment: Во-первых, попробуйте поискать `pyconfig.h` командой `sudo find / -name pyconfig.h`. Возможно, директория, в которой он лежит, не находится в стандартном пути поиска хедеров. В этом случае необходимо указать эту директроию в опции `-I` компилятора. Также посмотрите [эту](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914383/boost-python-cant-find-pyconfig-h-where-does-it-need-to-go) тему с SO, возможно, у вас та же проблема.

Comment: `locate pyconfig.h`